# Akka daily scheduled tasks

Tags: akka

I am preparing to rewrite my Play1 application with Play2 and I need to implement scheduled tasks that run exactly once a day at some specific time.
In my old app I implemented it as follows:

- the task is scheduled using Play1 jobs and the app runs on multiple nodes
- at the specified time all healthy nodes start the task and I use lock record in the database to ensure only one of them proceeds with execution and all others exit without doing anything.

How do I implement similar functionality with Akka?

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the [Scheduler](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/scheduler.html) to either execute a runnable or to send a message to an actor:

```
system.scheduler().scheduleOnce(Duration.create(24, TimeUnit.HOURS),
  taskActor, "doTask", system.dispatcher(), null);
```

Or

```
system.scheduler().scheduleOnce(Duration.create(24, TimeUnit.HOURS),
  new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      doTask()
    }
}, system.dispatcher());
```

I would prefer the method including an actor though.

You can read up on how to create an actor to receive the doTask message [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.12/java/untyped-actors.html).

Comment: The question is how do I do it in multi node environment and ensure the task doesn't run more than once per day, does Akka have any special features for that I I should implement it manally.

Comment: Multinode in terms of, every node runs the same code? In that case you probably need some kind of global state, like a message queue or a pub/sub system, where every node, can see what tasks need to be done currently.

Comment: Right, every node runs same code, and right need some global state, I though Akka may have something for global message queue

Comment: afaik no. But it provides interfaces for several message queue implementations like zeromq or camelmq. They also provide an event bus, but I'm not sure on how this can be clustered.